How to convert time values to text in Python?
I want to convert time values in cell into free text. For example:



start time
end time




12:01:24 AM
11:44:53 PM



then change if cell contains AM > Morning, PM > Noon



start time
end time
start time
end time




12:01:24 AM
11:44:53 PM
Morning
Noon



or if it is ok, I also want to group time such as  5:00:00 am to 11:59:59 pm > Morning, 12:00:00 PM to 5:00:00 pm to 5 > Afternoon,...
Does anyone know any functions in Python to convert like this? Thankyou

something like df["start time"].dt.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p') ?

python - How to check if a date time is before midday - Stack Overflow - you can use datetime without converting to string

I don't have your data - so I don't know if you really have it as time, datetime or string.
If you will have it as string then you can check if string ends with AM and/or PM
df['start group'] = ''  # create empty column for new text
df['end group'] = ''    # create empty column for new text

mask =  df['start time'].str.endswith('AM')
df.loc[mask, 'start group'] = 'Morning'
mask =  df['start time'].str.endswith('PM') 
df.loc[mask. 'start group'] = 'Noon'

mask =  df['end time'].str.endswith('AM') 
df.loc[mask, 'end group'] = 'Morning'
mask =  df['end time'].str.endswith('PM') 
df.loc[mask, 'end group'] = 'Noon'

You may also use one mask and later use ~ to revers it
df['start group'] = ''  # create empty column for new text
df['end group'] = ''    # create empty column for new text

mask = df['start time'].str.endswith('AM')
df.loc[ mask, 'start group'] = 'Morning'
df.loc[~mask, 'start group'] = 'Noon'

mask = df['end time'].str.endswith('AM')
df.loc[ mask, 'end group'] = 'Morning'
df.loc[~mask, 'end group'] = 'Noon'


If you have it as datetime (not time) then you can convert to string using .dt.strftime()
df['start time'] = df['start time'].dt.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
df['end time'] = df['end time'].dt.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')

See page: Python strftime reference cheatsheet

If you have it as datetime then you don't have to convert to string but but get .dt.time and compare with normal datetime.time
mask = df['start time'].dt.time < datetime.time(12)  # time(hour, minutes=0, seconds=0)

For you have as time then probably it wouldn't need .dt.time
mask = df['start time'] < datetime.time(12)  # time(hour, minutes=0, seconds=0)

but I didn't test it.

EDIT:
Example with numpy.where because it can assign 'Morning', 'Noon' in one line
import numpy as np

mask = df['start time'].str.endswith('AM')
df['start group'] = np.where(mask, 'Morning', 'Noon')

mask = df['end time'].str.endswith('AM')
df['end group']   = np.where(mask, 'Morning', 'Noon')


